# Trying to make a level up system

Tags: syntax-error

I'm trying to do a level up system for a game when I try to use the condition to exp upon using ">=" or even just "=" I get syntax error. I've looked for many sites and many questions here as well but nothing worked yet, I really wanted the ">=" way.

```
    Playername = x;
    Playerhp = 20*Playerlvl;
    Playerattack = 5*Playerlvl;
    Playerlvl = 1;
    Playerexp = 0;
    Levelup = Playerlvl + 1
    {


    if Playerexp > 100
     # TODO: Levelup
      else do nothing
    if condition:Levelup
    # TODO: print("Playername" Leveled Up to "Playerlvl")
```

Error:

```
   File "main.py", line 11
   if Playerexp > 100
    ^
   SyntaxError: invalid error
```

Comment: You're missing a colon character!

Comment: So I just need to add ":" after the "if"?